# Swapping tabs in android

Tags: android, tabview

I want to Swap or Switch with drag Between 3 tabs and for each tab there is a separate  Activity.. I tried it out with ScrollView but it does not work... Hope some one can help me out..

When i motion my finger over screen from right to left then the next tab content should be displayed. Am I clear i tried GestureListener but Failed.

M Sorry if this question is already asked i just can't find out the perfect solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by swapping? what are you expecting actually?

Comment: post your code !! no idea from your question

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `Activity`s to `Fragment`s and then use a `ViewPager` with `TabHost`.

You can get some good examples over the net. But for starters, this would be good -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html